# sed - get only text without extension

Tags: regex, sed

How do I remove the extension in this SED statement?

Through

```
sed 's/.* - //'
```

File content

```
2021-04-21_@fluffyban_6953588770591509765.mp4 - Filename.mp4
```

Actual

```
Filename.mp4
```

Desired

```
Filename
```

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, could you please explain, why first you first added regex tag by yourself and now removing it? Solutions given are having regex answers right.

Comment: Since there is no explanation given why tag is being added first and then removed and regex tag is looking relevant to this question, since many answers using regex style to answer question, I am adding it back here. In case someone is rolling it back then please to post a reason here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='2021-04-21_@fluffyban_6953588770591509765.mp4 - Filename.mp4'
sed -n 's/.* - \([^.]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => Filename
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/W5ztFC).

*Details*:

- `-n` - suppress default line output
- `s/` - substitute found pattern
- `.* - \([^.]*\).*` - any text, space, `-`, space, then any zero or more chars other than a dot captured into Group 1, and then any text
- `/\1/` - replace found matches with Group 1 value
- `p` - print the result of the substitution.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples only. This could be done with simple codes in `awk`,`sed` and `perl` as follows.

***1st solution:*** Using `sed`, perform simple substitutions and you will get desired output.

```
sed 's/.*- //;s/\.mp4$//' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `awk` its more simpler, creating different field separator and just print appropriate 2nd last column.

```
awk -F'- |.mp4' '{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using substitution method in `awk` to get the required value as per OP's requirement.

```
awk '{gsub(/.*- |\.mp4$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** With perl one liner we could grab the appropriate needed value by setting field separators as dash spaces and .mp4 as follows:

```
perl -a -F'-\s+|\.mp4'  -ne 'print "$F[$#F-1]\n";' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

The **Bash** way (which works in most similar shells such us `zsh`,`sh`,`ksh`) is:

```
fn="2021-04-21_@fluffyban_6953588770591509765.mp4 - Filename.mp4"

base=${fn%.*}
ext=${fn#$base.}

echo "$base"
echo "$ext"
```

Prints:

```
2021-04-21_@fluffyban_6953588770591509765.mp4 - Filename
mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk` you can also use a capture group to get the filename

```
match($0, /.* - ([^.]+)\.mp4$/, a) {print a[1]}' file
```

---

Regex explanation

- `.* -`  Match the last occurrence of  `-`
- `(` Capture **group 1** (Referred to by `a[1]` in the awk example)

  - `[^.]+` Match 1+ times any char except a dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.mp4$` Match `.mp4` at the end of the string

Awk explanation

```
awk '
match($0, /.* - ([^.]+)\.mp4$/, a) {  # Test if the line using $0 matches the pattern
  print a[1]                          # Print the value of group 1
}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `awk`:

```sh
awk '{sub(/\.[^.]+$/, ""); print $NF}' file

Filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 'BEGIN { FS = "( \- |[.][^. ]+$)"

    } NF > 2 { print $(NF-1) }'
```

no substr(), index(), match(), or sub() needed. If you're **VERY** certain  `" - "`  can only occur once, then

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "(^.* \- |[.][^. ]+$)"; OFS = "" } —-NF'
```